# If I don't need USB power what should I do?

Tags: power, usb, stm32

I am trying to conduct USB communication with a STM32F103RET6.

[image: Circuit Design]

I found [this article on USB power](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb2.shtml).

I think I need VBUS because any power will come from an external power source, so I connected VBUS to GND via a 0.1 µF capacitor.

Is this design correct?

Comment: Please note that if you directly connect the 1k5 resistor to 3.3V supply, the PC will try to communicate with the MCU, even if it is not ready yet for some reason. Expect problems and angry customers if you do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

VBUS is used as a signal that tells the device that a host is present. For a self-powered device, VBUS sensing is mandatory.

And the host and device must share GND.
You need to connect all four signals.

And the STM already has integrated series resistors.

You also need to ensure that the VBUS pin at the STM does not go above 4 V when powered off, and that the DP pull-up is enabled only when the device is ready. See the documentation, especially [AN4879: USB hardware and PCB guidelines using STM32 MCUs](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an4879-usb-hardware-and-pcb-guidelines-using-stm32-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), and [Management of VBUS sensing for USB device design](https://community.st.com/s/article/FAQ-Management-of-VBUS-sensing-for-USB-device-design).

[image: STM32 USB]

Comment: I read u r text now. But STM32F103RET6 has no VBUS pin.
That case, VBUS detection is all own to me?

Comment: Just use any digital input.

Comment: @CL.  You and a few more sources are saying that VBUS detection has to be handled by firmware if dedicated VBUS detection pin isn't available.  That will have to be my case.  I'm planning to use an STM32G474, and it doesn't have a dedicated VBUS detection pin.  What should the VBUS detection firmware look like?  Does the detection have to be fast and have an interrupt?  What should the firmware do if VBUS appears or disappears?  Is there a sample code for this somewhere?

Comment: @misk94555 That is a different question. Use the "Ask Question" button.